# Web Api dynamic url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to have one more parameter in my api, but it's not fixed. In this case {config} can be anything like config1, config2, config1433....

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{config}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I already tried to get the parameter and remove it from the request uri using a delegate handler, but it doesn't work because the url has been already analyzed.

Comment: You don't need to do anything elaborate, it would be pretty limiting if you could only have one parameter named "id". I like to use attribute routing, it is easier to make your routes anything you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I think it's a different case.  This parameter that I want to pass is independent of any controller or action. I don't want to pass it to all controllers or all actions.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: With attribute parameters I'll have decorate and read it in all my actions. And all my actions will have to receive this attribute. I want something more generic and earlier in web api stack. That's why I'm trying to use routeTemplate for that. Or, another option could be use it like a sub domain. Something like {config}.myhost.com/api/{controller}/{id}

Comment: You know you can map more than one route template? You can map as many as you want.

Comment: Yes, by I need to know the route before. In this case it is dynamic. The configuration comes from another api.  And I don't know how many will exist.

Comment: OK, now I get it. Sorry, I don't think I can help.

Comment: Much more important. You tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

First I had to inherit from DefaultHttpControllerSelector. Deriving this class allow you to customize the controller selection. In my case, it was that simple.

```
public class CustomControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    private HttpConfiguration _config;

    public IHttpControllerSelector PreviousSelector { get; set; }

    public CustomControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration):base(configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var uriSegments = request.RequestUri.Segments;
        var system = uriSegments[2];

        request.RequestUri = new System.Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(system, ""));

        var controllerDescriptor = PreviousSelector.SelectController(request);

        return controllerDescriptor;
    }
}
```

Than I had to replace the default one with my customization. But I saved the previous one because I used it after the url  manipulation.

```
var previousSelector = config.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector)) as IHttpControllerSelector;
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomControllerSelector(config) { PreviousSelector = previousSelector});
```

This was my reference.

[ASP.NET Web API custom IHttpControllerSelector for a single route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914776/asp-net-web-api-custom-ihttpcontrollerselector-for-a-single-route)